# Multi login using odbc

Tags: php, html, odbc

I need help how can I make this multi login (`usercp.php`) and (`Admincp.php`) using connection in database table name: (level).

```
<?php
session_start();
include('info.php');
$UserID = ms_escape_string($_POST['UserID']);
$Pw = ms_escape_string($_POST['Pw']);
$Error=0;

$res=odbc_exec($conn,"SELECT * FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master U
INNER JOIN PS_GameData.dbo.Chars UM ON UM.UserUID=U.UserUID
WHERE um.UserID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = '{$UserID}' 
AND  u.Pw COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = '{$Pw}'"); 

$row=odbc_num_rows($res);
if ($row == 0) {$Error++;}
if ($Error != 0){die ('You Cannot Login Without Atleast One Character');
}else{
header('Location: usercp.php');
}

?>
```

i already test this code but no lock its error i use this code

this in login: login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('info.php');
$UserID = ms_escape_string($_POST['UserID']);
$Pw = ms_escape_string($_POST['Pw']);
$Error=0;
$user=0;

$res=odbc_exec($conn,"SELECT * FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master U
INNER JOIN PS_GameData.dbo.Chars UM ON UM.UserUID=U.UserUID
WHERE um.UserID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = '{$UserID}' 
AND  u.Pw COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = '{$Pw}'"); 

$row=odbc_num_rows($res);
if ($row == 0) {$Error++;}
if ($Error != 0){die ('Incorrect Username or Password');
}else{
    $row = odbc_fetch_array($res);
    session_regenerate_id();
  $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $row['UserID'];
  $_SESSION['sess_password'] = $row['Pw'];
        $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] = $row['status'];

        echo $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
  session_write_close();

  if( $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "16"){
   header('Location: admincp.php');
  }else{
   header('Location: usercp.php');
  }

 }


?>
```

this for my Usercp.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $role = $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
    if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) || $role!="0"){
      header('Location: index.php?err=2');
    }
?>
```

this for my Admincp.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $role = $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
    if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) || $role!="16"){
      header('Location: index.php?err=2');
    }
?>
```

all this error please can u help me

Comment: Please describe the details on what is your purpose and what is the problem you met.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Comment: else{
 $row = odbc_fetch_array($res);
 session_regenerate_id();
  $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $row['UserID'];
  $_SESSION['sess_password'] = $row['Pw'];
        $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] = $row['status'];

        echo $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
  session_write_close();

  if( $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "16"){
   header('Location: admincp.php');
  }else{
   header('Location: usercp.php');
  }